# How to insert ads in a list view automatically?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, listview

I'd like to insert one add every 2 categories.
Currently, my `ListView` is fed with a map on categories.
Is here a compact way to transform the code to add `AdWidget()` the same way?

```dart
ListView(
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  children: widget.superCategory.allCategories
    .map((category) =>
       ClassifiedAdCategoryGalleryStrip(category: category))
       .toList(),
)
```

[UPDATE] `AdWidget()` is just an ad widget. You can replace by any widget, such as Text("ad widget here");

Currently my code is as follows:

```dart
final List<Widget> children = widget.superCategory.allCategories
        .map((category) => ClassifiedAdCategoryGalleryStrip(category: category))
        .toList();

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i += 2) {
      if (i == 0) continue;
      children.insert(i, Text("AdWidget"))
    }
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title:
                Text(i18n_category_gallery.i18n.fill([widget.superCategory]))),
        body: ListView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          children: children,
        ));
```

Comment: Can you share more details on what do you mean by `AdWidget()` and description for exactly what you wan to do

Comment: I've just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ListView.separated()`. this widget provides you something that you need .

also you may read this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-adding-separator-in-listview-c501fe568c76) to understand better what you are able to do with this widget